# Reading results of url request into python script

Tags: python, http

I am new to python and am trying to read the results of an http request with x parameters within a python script so that I can perform further tasks on it.

To me more specific, the request takes certain characteristics and sends back a list of files corresponding to the given parameters. Part of the resulting xml doc is a url for each file, which I am trying to access.

This is a segment of what I have so far, which prints the result of the request, but I only need to read part of the result.

```
import requests

link = "http://examplelink.com"
f = requests.get(link)

print f.text
```

I was thinking I could possibly do it as a string matching search for a url, but I'm almost positive there's an easier way. I am also using urllib in the program, so if thats a solution I'm totally open to it. I'm not tied to using requests.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: What part of the result do you need? Have you considered using lxml or beautifulsoup4 ?

Comment: +1 for beautiful soup, if the returned xml is super simple you could just roll your own regex too. could you please post the xml that is returned?

Comment: Most experienced people will advise you to avoid using regex on xml, html and other markup languages. BeautifulSoup4 is a good choice. Eventually you should also familiarise yourself with the possibilities inherent in products like selenium and scrapy which will considerably extend what you can do.

Comment: I don't think lxml and beautifulsoup would work because the results can also be returned as a json (if desired) (I could be totally off base about this, let me know if I'm wrong). Ideally I would just get the list of file URLs to iterate through.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show at least 3 Lines of Data from the `request(...` you get.